# Question about moment of inertia and velocity

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

First off, I swear this is not homework. I'm doing some practice problems because I got an exam coming up. I'm stuck on this one:
[image]

I figured I would use energy conservation for this problem. So since the thing is not moving initially, I tried doing

$mgh=\frac{1}{2} I\omega^2+\frac{1}{2} mv^2$, but that doesnt give me the right answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic setup is correct, conservation of energy might be the quickest way to go.

$$(m_1 -m_2) g h = \frac 1 2 I \omega^2 + \frac 1 2 (m_1+m_2) v^2, I=\frac{MR^2}{2}, \omega = v/R$$ gives me one of your options as the result.

The two $m$ in your formula seem to refer to different quantities.

Comment: Good, concise answer. Just to clarify, `MR^2/2` is the moment of inertia of a uniform disc around an axis passing through its center orthogonally to the plane of the circle.

Comment: you are indeed correct sir. Only question is, why do you subtract m1-m2 for potential energy?

Comment: @fprime: It's really `m_1gh - m_2gh` with the common factor taken out. There are two tensions on the rope due to the gravitational forces, in opposite directions.

Comment: @fprime: You identified the tricky part here (which was obvious to me because I worked from a Lagrangian and only later said that "yes, that was a waste of time, let's do it using conservation of energy"). Noldorin explains this correctly in the force picture, but in the energy picture I'd say "I wrote down the `change of energy' between the before and after states, not the absolute energies". The absolute  energy formulation is what the other other answer points out, for equivalent results.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the potential energy of $m_2$ which is at height $2h$ when $m_1$ hits the ground.

Comment: How would I use that?

Comment: You add it at the right hand side of the equation.

Comment: Thomas has taken that term from the right side of the equation to the left side. The subtraction gives the (m1-m2)gh expression (I am assuming that m is the total mass m1+m2 in your expression).